# How to click on soft keyboard 'search' button with Robotium test?

Tags: android, keyboard, robotium

I want to test next thing with Robotium: enter some text in search field, this I did, and click on soft keyboard 'search' button (android:imeOptions=actionSearch) which I am failing to do.
I tried with solo.sendKey(Solo.Enter) but no success. I am not sure if this is important, but soft keyboard is not shown at all - I tried to achieve that somehow but without success, also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally! [Robotium 5.1](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Changelog#Robotium_5.1) proudly presents to you `pressSoftKeyboardSearchButton()`.

For older versions you can use this code (isn't clean enough, but works):

```
solo.enterText(0, "ItemToSearchFor");
solo.sleep(1000);
solo.clickInList(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to send this keycode? 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_SEARCH 
something like this

solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);

Answer (score 0):

You can not use keycode, what you can do is to know the key position and press it. As soft keyboard is a bitmap, not a view.